# Vagrant communication between guest machines

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I have multiple Vagrant machines like so:

```
config.vm.define 'vagrant1' do |vagrant1|
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--natdnshostresolver1', 'on']
    end
    vagrant1.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
    vagrant1.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 80, host: 8080 
    vagrant1.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 443, host: 8443
    vagrant1.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 27017, host: 27017
    # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
    # using a specific IP.
    config.vm.network 'private_network', ip: '192.168.56.11'

    ENV['LC_ALL']='en_US.UTF-8'

end

config.vm.define 'vagrant2' do |vagrant2|
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--natdnshostresolver1', 'on']
    end
    vagrant2.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
    vagrant2.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 80, host: 8081
    vagrant2.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 443, host: 8444
    vagrant2.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 27017, host: 27018
    # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
    # using a specific IP.
    config.vm.network 'private_network', ip: '192.168.56.12'

    ENV['LC_ALL']='en_US.UTF-8'
end
```

What I would like is for `vagrant1` machine to be able to communicate with `vagrant2` machine. So far, I can connect from my host machines but the guest machines are unreachable to each other.

How do I enable communication between guest machines?

Comment: whats your virtualbox version and can you confirm you have guest additions on guest ? I just quickly test using vbox 5.1.10 and vagrant 1.9.2 - it works as expected, can `ping 192.168.56.12` from vagrant1 and vice versa

Comment: @FrédéricHenri 5.1.10 VBox and Vagrant Installed Version: 1.9.0. I used `https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest` to install guest additions right after I read your comments. Didnt help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok I spotted the error - you have wrong use of the config variable, everything you write as `config.vm.` is valid for all VMs even when its within a block so in your case it was creating multiple network interfaces.

So a simplified version of your Vagrantfile could be written as

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--natdnshostresolver1', 'on']
    end

    config.vm.define 'vagrant1' do |vagrant1|
        vagrant1.vm.network 'private_network', ip: '192.168.56.11'
        ENV['LC_ALL']='en_US.UTF-8'
    end

    config.vm.define 'vagrant2' do |vagrant2|
        vagrant2.vm.network 'private_network', ip: '192.168.56.12'
        ENV['LC_ALL']='en_US.UTF-8'
    end 

end
```

Note: you dont need to forward port when you're using a static IP as you can access directly from the IP

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the boxes together;

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.define 'vagrant1' do |vagrant1|
        config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--natdnshostresolver1', 'on']
        end
        vagrant1.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
        vagrant1.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 80, host: 8080 
        vagrant1.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 443, host: 8443
        vagrant1.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 27017, host: 27017
        # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
        # using a specific IP.
        config.vm.network 'private_network', ip: '192.168.56.11'

        ENV['LC_ALL']='en_US.UTF-8'

    end

    config.vm.define 'vagrant2' do |vagrant2|
        config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
            vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--natdnshostresolver1', 'on']
        end
        vagrant2.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
        vagrant2.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 80, host: 8081
        vagrant2.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 443, host: 8444
        vagrant2.vm.network 'forwarded_port', guest: 27017, host: 27018
        # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
        # using a specific IP.
        config.vm.network 'private_network', ip: '192.168.56.12'

        ENV['LC_ALL']='en_US.UTF-8'
    end 
end
```

Comment: oh I forgot to mention that these are defined inside the same `Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config| ` block.

Comment: Oh! Well, then I'm not sure. The [docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html) say this is possible in the way you've configured. How are you actually testing it?

Comment: pinging the static IP of the second machine after SSH-ing into the first